# TypeError in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I have no idea what is wrong! This is a very simple program and I have done a lot head banging! Please someone enlighten me!

This a lab problem from the CSE 111 - Programming Language II course. They teach Java at the university and the code I wrote in Java works fine.

I just have to create a Student class with some fields to hold the basic information about a student with methods to get and set the attributes. Then create an instance of that class and tryout the methods.
But every time I run this program the following error occurs:

```
TypeError: set_name() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)
```

Here is the code I wrote.

```
class Student:
    '''Student class'''

    name = None
    id = 0
    address = None
    cgpa = None

    def get_name():
        return name

    def set_name(n):
        name = n

    def get_id():
        return id

    def set_id(i):
        id = i

    def get_address():
        return address

    def set_address(a):
        address = a

    def get_cgpa():
        return cgpa

    def set_cgpa(c):
        cgpa = c


#An object of Student class
jack = Student()

jack.set_name('jacky')
print(jack.get_name())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not accepting a reference to your instance as the first argument to that method, i.e. your `set_name()` should be written:

```
def set_name(self, n):
    self.name = n
```

This is somewhat different from other languages where there is a built-in keyword (such as `this`) that refers to the current object. Python passes that reference explicitly, as an argument to the method.

All your other methods must be modified similarly.

Note that just setting `name = n` sets a local variable `name` which goes away when the method ends; it does not set anything on the instance.  You have to explicitly set `self.name` if you want an instance attribute.

Also, and this is a matter of style, but you do not usually write `set` and `get` methods in Python. It is normal practice to set and get attributes directly. If you want to do validation of values, use a property instead. So basically, none of your methods are actually necessary in good style.

However, you don't have an `__init__()` method. Usually you would pass the desired attributes of the instance when instantiating the class and save these on the instance.

```
class Student:

    def __init__(self, name, id, address, cgpa):
        self.name    = name
        self.id      = id
        self.address = address
        self.cgpa    = cgpa

herman = Student("Herman Munster", 12345, "1313 Mockingbird Lane", 4.0)
```

Comment: thank you very much! I am new to Python and I had no idea about `self` :/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import sys 
class Student:
   '''Student class'''

   self.name = None
   self.id = 0
   self.address = None
   self.cgpa = None

   def get_name(self):
       return self.name

   def set_name(self, n):
       self.name = n

   def get_id(self):
       return self.id

   def set_id(self, i):
       self.id = i

   def get_address(self):
       return self.address

   def set_address(self, a):
       self.address = a

   def get_cgpa(self):
       return self.cgpa

   def set_cgpa(self, c):
       self.cgpa = c
```

Comment: Thanks! You didn't have to rewrite though :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `self` as the first argument to each member function of the class. Member variables must then be referred to with `self`, i.e. `self.name`. Furthermore, you may wish to include an `__init__()` function; this serves usually to initialize any member variables, and is called at the instantiation of the class.

Take a look at the Python documentation here for some examples on well-formed classes: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks

Answer (score 1):

This is because first argument of methods is `self` - the class instance.

See [What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained)
and http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects

Comment: Thanks :) I didn't know about it since I am a beginner in Python.

Comment: @mnzrr, yes it's unusual, but comes handy when you work more with Python. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained

Comment: Thanks again warwaruk! I was following several books including A Byte of Python but didn't see anything about `self` :) I have to read more carefully >:(

Comment: Yes :) I accepted kindall's answer since it was more descriptive :)

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you need to pass in `self` for each of your member functions. You also need to reference class variables as `self.x`, if you want them to take an effect.

Here are a couple examples that you need to apply to the rest of your code.

```
   def set_name(self, n):
       self.name = n

   def get_cgpa(self):
       return self.cgpa
```

There is some explanation for why this is the case [in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks).